# Hibernate BasicExtractor doesn't log anything

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring 5.0.5, Hibernate 5.2.16 and logback. I want to log values of parameters bound to SQL queries Hibernate generates. I managed to get log output from BasicBinder (similar to `2018-09-28 15:27:03,228 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - [] binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [0]`) but I actually want output from BasicExtractor (similar to `17:34:50,362 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - extracted value ([id1_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]`). I think the BasicExtractor output is more readable. I followed the advice Thorben Janssen gave in [his article](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-logging-guide/) but to no avail.

Relevant part of logback configuration is:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor" level="ALL"/>
```

So, does anybody know how to see log output from `BasicExtractor`?

Comment: Hibernate used to need TRACE log level. Rise your log level to that. Sadly, it used to write a lot of crap too... so, YMMV.

Comment: @gorlok Thanks for the tip. I changed log levels to TRACE for all the loggers but unfortunately BasicExtractor is still not logged.

Comment: BasicExtractor translates SQL Types to Java Types from ResultSet. Code: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/sql/BasicExtractor.java Look this log example: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-log-sql-statements-and-their-parameters/

Comment: Try using the full class name `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor` in the logger configuration to give it a TRACE level. If that doesn't work, try using reflection to get the class name of the object in the `PROVIDER` static field in the `org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders` class. If it's not `Slf4jLoggerProvider`, then the jboss logger is not using logback as the back-end, and so it's ignoring your configuration.

Comment: @coladict Wow, excellent out-of-box thinking! I tried both ways and unfortunately still there's no BasicExtractor log even though the `PROVIDER` class is `org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider`.

Comment: For Hibernate 6, specify `<logger name="org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.extract" level="TRACE"/>`.